# Record IDs of features loaded on request in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, logging

I'm switching over to GeoServer, and we need to be able to record the number of features/polygons each user loads for licensing reasons.

I've got the Monitoring extension installed and the Auditing set up, but I can only see the ResponseLength.

Is there any way to be able to record the certain properties of a result from each request for a download of WFS data, whether by default or adding some kind of post-processing functionality? It'd need to be this way as opposed to just a count of the number of features to ensure that we're not counting each feature twice.

I'm fetching the data from a PostGIS database and returning to OpenLayers v4

Comment: do you mean upload or download? WMS or WFS?

Comment: To download WFS data